# Saving persons name and number

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I very new to android programming, so this may come as very simple question. I’m trying to create my own app that can save someone’s name and phone number to my phone. I would like that this information can then be visible in apps like “Phone, Contacts, Messaging, …” that already came with phone. Any guide would be helpful.

Comment: So you want to enter that information into the app then how do you want to access them again? If you are totally new to android, I would highly recommend a good tutorial on android development. This will save you a lot of guesswork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to allow permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

The import `import android.provider.ContactsContract;` in your MainActivity file.

As you are a newbie i would like you to follow [this](http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/working-with-android-contacts/) tutorial for working with contacts.